# Пунктуация: ...- это (,) чтобы

Tags: пунктуация

Единственное пожелание - это, чтобы она продолжала своё существование.

Нужна ли запятая? Можно ли написать так: "единственное пожелание - чтобы она продолжала своё существование"?

И правильная ли пунктуация во втором вопросе?

Answer (score 4):

Единственное пожелание ― это чтобы она продолжала своё существование.

Единственное пожелание ― чтобы она продолжала своё существование.

В данном случаев придаточное предложение выступает в роли **сказуемого**, **ЭТО** ― **связка**, которая может отсутствовать.

**Пример:** Самое важное ― это чтобы тебя наполняло сознание, что ты не зря живешь (Александр Клейн).

Придаточное с союзом ЧТОБЫ часто встречается **в качестве самостоятельной единицы**, например: Это чтобы водяной не гневался и послал на крючок побольше рыбы, ― пояснил Андреич.  Это чтобы сбить меня с толку.

Comment: большое спасибо!